# ¿como hacer un botón guardar todo, si se editan las pestañas en un JtabbedPane?

Tags: java

```
public void saveAllEditor() {
    JFileChooser agregar = new JFileChooser();


    int text = agregar.showOpenDialog(this);

    if (text == agregar.APPROVE_OPTION) {

    File documentos = agregar.getSelectedFile();
    setTitle(documentos.getName());




    try {
        PrintWriter bw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(documentos,true));
        bw.write(edit.getArea().getText()+"\t");


        bw.close();
        edit = new Editor(agregar.getSelectedFile());
        tbContenedor.add(agregar.getName(agregar.getSelectedFile()), edit);
        tbContenedor.setSelectedComponent(edit);

    } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿A donde o en que componentes guardas tu informacion?

Comment: a una clase que se llama Editor y la llame "edit" ahi es en donde tengo mi textArea

Comment: y se guardar en algun objeto o varable?

Comment: lo que hace este programa es que tu puedes crear y abrir archivos y si tu abres o creas muchos archivo se te abren en pestañas, lo que quiero hacer yo es que si el usuario edito alguno o varios archivos al momento de presionar el boton de saveall me pregunte si quiero guardar lo que edite en los archivos y me guarde lo editado en su respectivo archivo.

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una de las formas basicas de hacer que un boton ejecute una accion tu decides que quieres que se ejecute con su accion.

```
public class Guarda{

public Guarda(){

  JTextArea areaTexto;
  String texto;
  JButton btn = new JButton(); 
         btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
             @Override
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                texto = areaTexto.getText();
                 //Aqui puedes meter la funcionalidad de tu aplicacion
                 //Para guardar los datos que desees.
              }
          });
  }

}
```